# Why eclipse starts building all when I save a txt file?

Tags: java, eclipse

Why does eclipse start `building all` whenever I save a txt file? How can I set eclipse to avoid this?

My textfile isn't in src package.

Comment: Is your Textfile in a src package?

Comment: keeo you text file in resources not in src package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude single or multiple files from building. Right click on project select `Properties`. Go to `Java Build Path` in `Source` tab add this text file in excluded list. Refer pic below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

de select the  nder Project. It will stop building after your save.

Project -> Build Automaticaly

if this option is selected then save on any file trigger the build. Oither option would be move your text file out of source folder if possible.